# Grant permission to create a user for any database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm working with SQL Server 2012.
There are two permissions.
Server-level permission to create logins:

```
GRANT ALTER ANY LOGIN TO MyAdminUser
```

And database-level permission to create users:

```
USE aDatabase
GRANT ALTER ANY USER TO MyAdminUser
```

Is there are any equivalent of server-level way (as in case with ALTER ANY LOGIN permission) to grant my MyAdminUser permission to create users for any database? I mean permissions lower then CONTROL SERVER, and without assigning this user to any roles (such as sysadmin).
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like

```
USE master
GRANT ALTER ANY DATABASE TO MyAdminUser
```

Does the trick but I'm not sure it's the best way to achieve my goal :-/